# ImportError: cannot import name 'ops'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My version is : Python 3.6.8
keras:2.6.0
tensorflow:2.6.0

when I try: `from keras import ops`

It got this: `cannot import name 'ops'`

How do I solve this issue?
Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to use keras 3 command so u need to upgrade your keras.

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```

You will also needed to update your  tensorflow to avoid several incompatibilities

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```